# nmake appending to variables

Tags: makefile, nmake

- Utility: NMake
- Platform : Windows 7

I have the following Makefile

```
FILE = $(shell) *.c
FILE += $(shell) *.cpp

exec:
    @echo $(FILE)
```

This works perfectly fine with make. This throws up the following error with nmake

```
makefile(2) : fatal error U1036: syntax error : too many names to left of '='
Stop.
```

What could be the reason?

Without the line

```
FILE += $(shell) *.cpp
```

nmake works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+=` syntax is a [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) extension that was pioneered in Sun's `make` in the late 80s.  It is not part of the syntax for POSIX standard [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), or the original AT&T [`make`](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/vol2/make).

If you use extensions, you get caught when you switch to a system that doesn't support them.  You either have to rework things (hard) or stick with the original system.

---

One way to modify the file to work with `nmake` is probably:

```
FILE1 = $(shell) *.c
FILE2 = $(shell) *.cpp
FILE  = $(FILE1) $(FILE2)

exec:
    @echo $(FILE)
```

Or, given that the macro `shell` is not defined, even:

```
FILE1 = *.c
FILE2 = *.cpp
FILE  = $(FILE1) $(FILE2)

exec:
    @echo $(FILE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
FILE = $(shell) *.c
FILE += $(shell) *.cpp
```

you must use

```
FILE = $(shell) *.c
FILE = $(shell) *.cpp $(FILE)
```

The expansion strategy is different from nmake and make. nmake expands all before starting evaluating the rules while make does it just in times when needed and because this gives problems it has the two flavours of expansion as described in the info pages.

I personally like nmake's way better. And by the way, use "jom" instead of "nmake".

Comment: The last line is likely to lead to a 'recursive macro' error.